# Hyperlink in the description of the NuGet package in .nuspec

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec, nuspec

I'm developing a NuGet package and keep it open source at github.com

My package after installation requires a few configuration steps to be done in VS solution, and I document this in README.md file on github.

I'd like to reference this README.md file in the NuGet package, so that people know what to do after package installation.

I've specified `<projectUrl>` in my **.nuspec** file pointing to my Git repo on github.
But it's not obvious for users that they need to click it to read documentation.

I'd like to make it loud and clear for users to follow the link to read full documentation.
It would be nice to have a hyperlink, for example in the `<description>` field of the **.nuspec** file, so it's displayed as a hyperlink on the:

- project page on nuget.org
- package details shown in Visual Studio when browsing \ installing the package

I've tried different ways to add a link, for example XML-escaping `<` and `>` as `&lt;` and `&gt;` but it doesn't show it as a link, but just as an html text.

Comment: Showing a hyperlink is not supported. The only thing you could possibly do is include a readme.txt file in your NuGet package. That will be opened by Visual Studio when you install the NuGet package.

Comment: Thank you! It's an interesting idea. Will go this route for now. If you want - post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The < licenseUrl> and < projectUrl> are the two tags which will show hyperlink in the NuGet package manager. You cannot provide hyperlinks in any other tags. If you want to provide a hyperlink use any of these. Otherwise, you can use a readme file.